# Remove URL Prefix from String (http:/, www, etc.)

Tags: java, android, string, url, textview

I need to remove all kinds of "web beginnings" from my String

My TextView must be without "http://" , "http:// www." , "www." and other URL prefixes.

Please can you help me to to this ?

Comment: I don't know no android, but isn't there something like a replace function for string ? Then you could simply replace those strings with an empty string and that's it...

Comment: Your use of "web beginnings" tells me that you may need to learn some URI scheme fundamentals before taking on this project.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do that by using regular expression

```
"www.aaa".replaceFirst("^(http[s]?://www\\.|http[s]?://|www\\.)","")
```

Comment: The ordering of the regex disjunction matters here - it should be `replaceFirst("^(http://www\\.|http://|www\\.)","")` to work for the `http://www.` case.

Comment: @Josh you're right. I've fixed my answer. thanks.

Comment: @kingori , what to do if we are not sure if the url begins with http or https .

Comment: And since the question says other URL prefixes, this needs to be updated to include https too.

```"www.aaa".replaceFirst("^(https://www\\.|http://www\\.|http://|https://|www\\.)","");```

Comment: @IshanThilinaSomasiri good point. I've appended (?>s) to http to handle https cases.

Comment: @kingori `(?>s)` appears to only match https cases, to match both http and https, it should be `^(http[s]?://www\.|http[s]?://|www\.)`

Comment: @NoHarmDan oh, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: In Kotlin
`"www.aaa".replaceFirst("^(http[s]?://www\\.|http[s]?://|www\\.)".toRegex(),"")`

Answer (score 83):

Use an instance of `URI` and use it to split however you want:

```
URI uri = new URI(whateverYourAddressStringIs);
String path = uri.getPath(); // split whatever you need
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html

Comment: The code appears to be using `java.net.URI` but you link to `android.net.Uri` without any comments. That's a bit weird.

Comment: The correct way would be: Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com");

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Both URI and Uri `getPath()` return an empty String when `http://` or `https://` is included in the address. If the address starts with `www.`, `getPath()` includes it too. This therefore is not the right answer.

Comment: Warning: `getPath()` leaves out the query and fragment parts of the Uri

Comment: I think you should use `getHost()` instead of `getPath()` and you will need to remove www later if needed.

Comment: You should use `getAuthority()` instead of `getPath()`

Answer (score 11):

you can use String replace.

```
String myString = "http://www.abc.com";
myString.replace("http://","").replace("http:// www.","").replace("www.","");
```

Comment: Same comment as on the accepted answer, `"www."` might be present somewhere else in the URL, you should only remove it from the start.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that when you say "web beginnings", you mean "protocols". You can learn more about URLs in the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL).

Generally speaking, you cannot remove "www." from a URL and guarantee that the URL will point to the same host. If all you want to do is hide it from the user, that's fine, but I personally find that annoying.

The following code will strip all protocols that Java knows about, not just http. Not all protocols have a //, so you have to manually check that. The [Java URL class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) can break down the URL as precisely as you want it.

```
import java.net.URL;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(args[0]);
            String protocol = url.getProtocol();
            String result = args[0].replaceFirst(protocol + ":", "");
            if (result.startsWith("//"))
            {
                result = result.substring(2);
            }

            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.replace() method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html